# How to release memory of global variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to release all the memory of global variables after I log out. Because, after I log out, the memory doesn't go down. I'm using ARC.

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
global.arrayStatus = nil;
global.arrayEmpName = nil;
global.arrayEmpNo = nil;
global.arrayDateTime = nil;
global.arraUpdatedBy = nil;
global.arrayDatePosted = nil;
global.arrayPostStatus = nil;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: How are you testing memory usage?

Comment: Try to use the Allocations instrument to see where memory has been allocated. It sounds like the things your are deleting use less memory than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

How large are the objects you are clearing? It could be that they are so small you're not noticing any visible memory change.

Check out [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html) on the Instruments tool, specifically the leaks section

Note that you may also have a [retain cycle](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html), which would avoid memory being purged and would also not show up in instruments

On a side note, if you are clearing all properties of your global object, then perhaps it could be easier just replacing it with a new instance, rather than clearing each of its properties.

```
//  Beats writing more than one line
global = [[GlobalObject alloc] init];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to not use super delloc in arc

```
    -(void)dealloc{
    global.arrayStatus = nil;
    global.arrayEmpName = nil;
    global.arrayEmpNo = nil;
    global.arrayDateTime = nil;
    global.arraUpdatedBy = nil;
    global.arrayDatePosted = nil;
    global.arrayPostStatus = nil;
    }
```